# Can Opening a Switch Cause a Short Circuit?

Tags: switches, ground, short-circuit

Is it possible to construct a simple circuit (sans transistors) that would cause a short circuit between two points when a switch is opened? My intuition says no, but I don't have any proof for such a claim.

Comment: Does simple include a relay and a DC supply? If so, it's easy as long as the relay has a normally-closed contact...

Comment: what's the reason to have the short circuit when the switch is *opened*? because, you know, a switch creates a nice short circuit when it closes.

Comment: Sounds like an SPDT switch would check the boxes.

Answer (score 3):

Put an inductor in the circuit, and some device that fails as a short circuit on overvoltage.

Comment: why not add a circuit to show an example?

Answer (score 0):

No.  Not without a transistor, relay, or something similar.

Comment: Why not add a bit of explanation of why it requires an amplifying element?